# grouping json list into date and further grouping into specific field

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm having difficulty in grouping json into date specific groups and further grouping the result into specific field

here's the example json

```
            {
              "list":[
                {
                  "category":"League",
                  "list":[
                    {
                      "id":16389,
                      "matchDesc":"1st Match",
                      "seriesId":2430,
                      "seriesDesc":"group A",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1460212200,
                      "teamAName":"Mumbai Indians",
                      "teamAShortName":"MUM",
                      "teamBName":"Rising Pune Supergiants",
                      "teamBShortName":"RPS",
                      "teamAImageId":0,
                      "teamBImageId":0,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    },
                    {
                      "id":16390,
                      "matchDesc":"2nd Match",
                      "seriesId":2430,
                      "seriesDesc":"group A",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1460298600,
                      "teamAName":"Kolkata Knight Riders",
                      "teamAShortName":"KOL",
                      "teamBName":"Delhi Daredevils",
                      "teamBShortName":"DEL",
                      "teamAImageId":0,
                      "teamBImageId":146957,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    },
                    {
                      "id":16391,
                      "matchDesc":"3rd Match",
                      "seriesId":2430,
                      "seriesDesc":"group B",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1460385000,
                      "teamAName":"Kings XI Punjab",
                      "teamAShortName":"MOH",
                      "teamBName":"Gujarat Lions",
                      "teamBShortName":"GL",
                      "teamAImageId":0,
                      "teamBImageId":0,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    },
                    {
                      "id":16085,
                      "matchDesc":"South Group",
                      "seriesId":2422,
                      "seriesDesc":"group B",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1463702400,
                      "teamAName":"Essex",
                      "teamAShortName":"Ess",
                      "teamBName":"Surrey",
                      "teamBShortName":"Sur",
                      "teamAImageId":0,
                      "teamBImageId":0,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    },
                    {
                      "id":16086,
                      "matchDesc":"South Group",
                      "seriesId":2422,
                      "seriesDesc":"group C",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1463702400,
                      "teamAName":"Gloucestershire",
                      "teamAShortName":"Gloucs",
                      "teamBName":"Sussex",
                      "teamBShortName":"SUS",
                      "teamAImageId":0,
                      "teamBImageId":0,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    },
                    {
                      "id":16087,
                      "matchDesc":"South Group",
                      "seriesId":2422,
                      "seriesDesc":"group C",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1463702400,
                      "teamAName":"Kent",
                      "teamAShortName":"KENT",
                      "teamBName":"Somerset",
                      "teamBShortName":"SOM",
                      "teamAImageId":0,
                      "teamBImageId":0,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    },
                    {
                      "id":16412,
                      "matchDesc":"24th Match",
                      "seriesId":2430,
                      "seriesDesc":"group B",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1461853800,
                      "teamAName":"Mumbai Indians",
                      "teamAShortName":"MUM",
                      "teamBName":"Kolkata Knight Riders",
                      "teamBShortName":"KOL",
                      "teamAImageId":0,
                      "teamBImageId":0,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    },
                    {
                      "id":16413,
                      "matchDesc":"25th Match",
                      "seriesId":2430,
                      "seriesDesc":"group B",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1461940200,
                      "teamAName":"Rising Pune Supergiants",
                      "teamAShortName":"RPS",
                      "teamBName":"Gujarat Lions",
                      "teamBShortName":"GL",
                      "teamAImageId":0,
                      "teamBImageId":0,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    },
                    {
                      "id":16414,
                      "matchDesc":"26th Match",
                      "seriesId":2430,
                      "seriesDesc":"group A",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1462012200,
                      "teamAName":"Delhi Daredevils",
                      "teamAShortName":"DEL",
                      "teamBName":"Kolkata Knight Riders",
                      "teamBShortName":"KOL",
                      "teamAImageId":146957,
                      "teamBImageId":0,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    },
                    {
                      "id":16440,
                      "matchDesc":"52nd Match",
                      "seriesId":2430,
                      "seriesDesc":"group A",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1463754600,
                      "teamAName":"Delhi Daredevils",
                      "teamAShortName":"DEL",
                      "teamBName":"Sunrisers Hyderabad",
                      "teamBShortName":"HYD",
                      "teamAImageId":146957,
                      "teamBImageId":0,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
```

Note: I have already converted json into gson so that i could use pojo for iteration but i'm facing difficulty in grouping

i'm expecting output as matches which are scheduled per date and grouped by the 'seriesDesc' field

Thanks

EDIT:
i'm expecting the o/p something similler to this

```
11/08/2016 (considering system time and comparing with timeStamp of object 'startDate')
group A (Considering object 'seriesDesc')
match1
match2

groupB
match1
match2

groupC
match1
match2
match3

12/08/2016
 group A
 match1
 match2

 groupB
 match1
 match2

 groupC
 match1
 match2
 match3
```

Note: match =      {
                      "id":16389,
                      "matchDesc":"1st Match",
                      "seriesId":2430,
                      "seriesDesc":"group A",
                      "category":"League",
                      "status":"",
                      "startDate":1460212200,
                      "teamAName":"Mumbai Indians",
                      "teamAShortName":"MUM",
                      "teamBName":"Rising Pune Supergiants",
                      "teamBShortName":"RPS",
                      "teamAImageId":0,
                      "teamBImageId":0,
                      "isPrevDay":false
                    }

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected output?

Comment: added expected output

Comment: Please show the code you have already written to do the grouping

Comment: please refer the github link for  complete information [link] https://github.com/madroidpro/Cricbuzz/blob/master/app/src/main/java/madroid/cricbuzz/activity/MainActivity.java

Comment: And this `match1`, `match2`  is the `matchDescription` ?

Comment: no these are the complete matched arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got:

```
String json = ...;

JsonElement el = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
// Get inner list
JsonArray list = el.getAsJsonObject()
    .get("list").getAsJsonArray()
    .get(0).getAsJsonObject()
    .get("list").getAsJsonArray();

// Make into a regular list, so we can stream
List<JsonObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
list.forEach(e -> objects.add(e.getAsJsonObject()));

// Group by date, then by series description
Map<LocalDate, Map<String, List<JsonObject>>> result = objects.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            e -> LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                Instant.ofEpochSecond(e.get("startDate").getAsLong()),
                    ZoneId.systemDefault()
            ).toLocalDate(),
            Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.get("seriesDesc").getAsString())
        )
    );      

// Sorted printing
result.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .forEach(date -> {
        System.out.println(date.getKey());
        date.getValue().entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .forEach(group -> {
                System.out.println(group.getKey());
                group.getValue().forEach(System.out::println);
                System.out.println();
            });
    });
```

Comment: This is what i was expecting.. also got to know about lambda expressions, thanks